# Storage Queue Connection String Environment variable

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there an environment variable I can set in my azure app settings to have a function pick up my storage queue connection string? I've been looking over the source and I don't see anything.

But I do see this section (https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-run-local.md#to-run-locally) about running locally and being able to specify a connection string. I can't ship a connection string in my oss app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here are the steps for setting the App Setting for your Function App:

1. Visit your Function App through the Azure Functions Portal in the browser.
2. Click on the **Function app settings** button located on the bottom left.
3. Click on **Configure app settings** to load the app settings blade.
4. Scroll down to the **App settings** section, and add the key and value pair for your storage queue connection.
5. Click on the **Save** button.

Answer (score 0):

`son
 "queueBinding": {
      "properties": {
        "queueName": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The queue name."
        },
        "connection": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "An app setting (or environment variable) with the storage connection string to be used by this binding."
        }
      }`

After looking at the spec it appear this is possible by just putting the environment variable name for the connection.